# Is it possible to use both align and size parameters for images in MoinMoin?

Tags: images, wiki, embed

I'm getting a `500 Internal Server Error` if I try something like `{{attachment:image.png|alt text|width=100 align="left"}}`, both in the wiki I am actually trying to edit (https://live.gnome.org/) and in the MoinMoin wiki sandbox (http://moinmo.in/action/edit/WikiSandBox).

The examples at [moinmo.in/HelpOnLinking](http://moinmo.in/HelpOnLinking#line-42) show how to use both parameters, but never combining them in the same image. It definitely seems to be possible to use more than one parameter (e.g. width and height), but the combination of width and align apparently brings the wiki engine down. Is there something I'm overlooking?

How can I add a thumbnail of an image to a page in a MoinMoin wiki without using the default alignment (inline with text)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While researching to ask this question, I came across [this bug report](http://moinmo.in/MoinMoinBugs/AlignTopAlignLeft), which seems to describe the same problem (see the "Comments" section). So apparently this is indeed a bug in MoinMoin. Hopefully they'll fix it sometime soon...